# Small Text Box Appears in Excel Workbook -- Cannot Remove

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2E00.png]

There is a small blank white box, like a text box, appearing in my workbook.  This cannot be removed by right clicking. When inserting more rows, the box moves along with the rows and cannot be removed. You can enter text in this box.

Comment: That looks like a text box. You can go to "Developer" tab, click on "Design Mode" and you will be able to select and delete that box. If you don't have the "Developer" tab active you have to go to "Customize Ribbon" and do so, by checking the option in the right table.